# Dependent attributes?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

I searched through a number of posts but didn't quite see any specific to what I'm looking for - or at least not with a sufficient answer to what I need.

We are going to be selling a product with an option for a customization (imprinting).  Imprinting requires selecting a color and a font for the imprint, but the color and font are only relevant if the customer wants to add imprinting to the product.

Is it possible (using the existing Magento 2 gui tools) to have an option that will only display when another option is selected to a particular value, or will this have to be codified or otherwise done with an aftermarket plugin?

Another thing I considered was that I saw it supports both 'related products' and 'upsell' options. Presumably I could create a parallel configurable product description 'with' imprinting default and show it as some kind of an up-sell option on the product 'without' imprinting or the extra two options. But this leaves me to wonder if there is any kind of 'duplicate' or 'clone' product to create the starting point for the 'upsell' version without having to enter all the [shared] information again manually?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ad 1.

It is not possible to do with core Magento2 functionality

2. Ad 2.

   This is not very good solution, you will have to take care of many "clone" products which should be logically treated as the same product. You will encounter problems with erp integrations (entity_id=>erp_id will not work, you will have to add more attributes which will yield in artificial and not very intuitive results), managing and updating products (while you might want to update some aspect of product you will have to remember to update all "clone" products). These are some of the first impression issues you will have to deal with. The best solution is to develop dedicated solution or to buy module (the last will be real money saver unless you are building something big, then i would never recommend any module from market since most are rather bad). So in short, your initial assumptions are correct, such a solution will be too artificial.

Comment: I figured as much. But it's hard to determine if a given module is designed to do specifically the sort of thing I'm looking for. The descriptions leave a lot to be desired on most of the ones I have found.